# Python: looking for a quick way to count records based on feature conditions

Tags: python, filtering, record, counting

My maiden post!

**Set up**
I have a project where I am given a bunch of records in an Excel file, and I am tasked with doing 'Excel Gymnastics' on it in order to get counts of certain records based on a series of criteria.

This Excel Gymnastics is a series of mouse clicks on various columns where I select different values for all of the columns to reduce the number of records, then count the remaining records and put that number into a different spreadsheet.

For example: say I have an inventory of animals in a zoo. Each record represents a different animal, and the columns represent all the features used to describe animals.

Let's say I am tasked with looking for all the snakes in the zoo: I would set the 'blooded' filter to 'cold', the 'arms/legs' filter to 'none', the 'breathing-mechanism' filter to 'lungs. The resulting list of records would be all the snakes in the zoo. I would count the number of records, document that number in a different spreadsheet in a cell with the label 'snakes', and move onto the next animal to count.

**Question**
Is there a thing I should be reading up on in Python to achieve this?

Ideally, I'd like to have two files:

1. the *records I want to count* (11 columns of features, all strings, with 3-4 possible values for each feature; 100,000 records)
2. a *numbered list of the conditions* used to count the records; this would basically be a stack of all possible outcomes for all features

The output report would be a list of counts, each count representing an item in the *numbered list of conditions*.
Thanks,

Nick

I have looked into boolean/binary indexing, but the examples given seem to point to numeric arrays or how to construct dataframes with true/false indexes.

Comment: a good approach is to import your data into a pandas dataframe, apply standard filter and count methods. Everything should work more or less out of the box; your data is small, this should be fast

Comment: Also: Hi Nick, welcome! You are much more likely to have a successful question if you provide a very specific example with data and expected output.

Comment: Hi @anon01,

Thank you for your reply.

I have gone down the Pandas path, and it took app. 35 minutes to generate the results. What I think might point to the speed issue is the sheer volume of possible combinations of filters I have to run against the records (435,000 ish).

Does a process, like what you described above, exist using Numpy string arrays? My understanding is that Numpy is faster at doing certain things than Pandas, although it might be more difficult to code. 

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Filter should be pretty fast - it sounds like something isn't optimized. I would recommend you open a new question (or rewrite this) with the updated info, including source data and filters

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to get the features themselves programmatically from an Excel file, or do you already have all the animals and their given features and you're looking for how to store and reference them?

If you're looking for the latter, you could make a nested dictionary with each animal and its features. For example:

```
animals = {"snake" : {"blooded":"cold", "breathing-mechanism":"lungs"},...}
```

Then when you have to interact with Excel (I'm also assuming you have to use Python to interact with the literal filter functions in Excel, not just extract filtered data), you would just set each filter equal to

```
animals[animal][filter]
```

If you also need to get the filter values programmatically (i.e. you're told to find all snakes but aren't allowed to see the file first), I would recommend looking up how to import excel data into a pandas dataframe, and how to get the index of unique values from a pandas dataframe.

Once you get the indices of unique values in your "animals" column, you can reference the row of each unique index and add the data from each column in that row to a dictionary like the one shown above, and continue with your Excel gymnastics.